# Scheduled Executor Service isn't working

Tags: java, scheduled-tasks

I want a specific task to run everyday (every 24 hours). I used a scheduled executor service but after I tested it with 20 seconds to see if the task would run, it didn't. Am I doing something wrong?
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors
            .newScheduledThreadPool(1);

    scheduler.scheduleWithFixedDelay(new TimerTask() {
        public void run() {
            ArrayList<Integer> people = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            try {
                shelf.g.setOverdue();
                for (int i = 1; i < 1000; i++) {
                    if (shelf.book[i] != null
                            && shelf.book[i].checkedOut != null) {
                        if (shelf.book[i].overdue == true) {
                            for (int i2 = 0; i < 600; i++) {
                                if (account.person[i] == null) {
                                    account.person[i] = new account();
                                }
                                if (account.person[i2].name
                                        .equalsIgnoreCase(shelf.book[i].personName)) {
                                    people.add(i2);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                Set<Integer> s = new LinkedHashSet<Integer>(people);
                people = new ArrayList<Integer>(s);
                ArrayList<String> books = new ArrayList<String>();

                Properties props = new Properties();
                Session session = Session.getInstance(props);
                MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);
                Transport t = null;
                Address from = new InternetAddress(
                        "LGCCLibrary42@gmail.com", "LGCC Library");
                for (int i = 0; i < people.size(); i++) {
                    for (int i2 = 1; i2 < 1000; i2++) {
                        if (shelf.book[i2] != null
                                && shelf.book[i2].checkedOut != null) {
                            if (shelf.book[i2].overdue == true) {
                                if (account.person[people.get(i)].name
                                        .equalsIgnoreCase(shelf.book[i2].personName)) {

                                    books.add("Book " + i2 + " - " + shelf.book[i2].bookName
                                            + "\n");

                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    String thePerson = account.person[people.get(i)].name;
                    Address to = new InternetAddress(account.person[people
                            .get(i)].eMail);

                    msg.setText(thePerson
                            + " , you have the following books overdue"
                            + "\n" + books.toString().replace("[", "").replace("]", ""));
                    msg.setFrom(from);
                    msg.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, to);
                    msg.setSubject("LGCC library overdue books");

                    t = session.getTransport("smtps");
                    t.connect("smtp.gmail.com", "LGCCLibrary42", "4JesusChrist");
                    t.sendMessage(msg, msg.getAllRecipients());
                    books.clear();
                }
                t.close();

            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Something went wrong",
                        "Alert", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);


            } catch (AddressException ex) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Something went wrong",
                        "Alert", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);

            } catch (MessagingException ex) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Something went wrong",
                        "Alert", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);

            }
        }
    }, 0, 24, TimeUnit.HOURS);
```

Comment: Have you tried a using Runnable instead of TimerTask?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As @JeremeyFarrell said, use a `Runnable` instead of a `TimerTask`; there is no functionality or benefit to be gained from using a `TimerTask`.

I've simplified your code and it just works without problems:

```
ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors
        .newScheduledThreadPool(1);

scheduler.scheduleWithFixedDelay(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Do something useful");
    }
}, 0, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

The most likely cause of your problem can be found in the Javadoc of `scheduleWithFixedDelay`:

> If any execution of the task encounters an **exception**, subsequent
>   executions are suppressed.

You probably had an exception, possibly a `RuntimeException` (such as a `NullPointerException`), which stopped further invocations.

One way to solve that is to catch all exceptions and log them.

```
scheduler.scheduleWithFixedDelay(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        try {
            doTheRealWork(); // Such as "sendEmail()"
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace(); // Or better, use next line if you have configured a logger:
            logger.error("Exception in scheduled e-mail task", e);
        }
    }
}, 0, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

(Note: of course, replace `1, TimeUnit.SECONDS` with `24, TimeUnit.HOURS` once you are satisfied that things work as expected)

A few things to point out:

- You're calling `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog` from a Thread that is not the UI thread. Swing doesn't support doing UI work from any thread except the main UI thread; if you still do, you can get all kinds of race conditions.
- In any case, even if that wasn't a problem, you're blocking your scheduled thread on user interaction; someone has to press "OK" before you application can continue
- But this doesn't *cause* your problem.

Comment: I got it fixed now, thanks. I also wanted to ask, will the task run even if the application is not running/active. If not, are there anyways to ensure that the task will execute even when the program isn't opened or running?

Comment: it won't call when device is in sleep mode.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible an exception occurs within the Task or also Runnable. You will not recognize it. Try to implement something very simple first. Like a System.out.println("hello world").
Once this runs, work your way up to a more complex implementation.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take a look at the other answers that were given before. Your approach is mentioned there already. In order to keep the site clear and make it easy to find answers, we try to avoid double answers.